# Javascript navigating class in for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to go to the location json.responseJSON.Sites.LHR and on next iteration json.responseJSON.Sites.NJE  so on and so on. notification on the first instance is a string "LHR" and second "NJE".
Is this possible?

```
    for(var notification in json.responseJSON.Sites){
            console.log(json.responseJSON.Sites.notification);
    }
```

This is my json

```
{
"Sites": {
    "LHR": 1,
    "NJE": 1,
    "AZS": 1,
    "SGP": 1,
    "OHS": 1,
    "AZP": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(json.responseJSON.Sites[notification]);`

Answer (score 2):

You may have to access it as property access notation (instead of object.property do object['property']) such as:

```
  responseJSON = {
"Sites": {
    "LHR": 1,
    "NJE": 1,
    "AZS": 1,
    "SGP": 1,
    "OHS": 1,
    "AZP": 1
  }
};

for(var notification in responseJSON.Sites){
    console.log(notification + " : " + responseJSON.Sites[notification]);
    }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fqk8bdw/1/

Comment: There's no array here.  Why would you describe it that way?   `responseJSON.Sites[notification]` is just one way of accessing a property value.

Comment: Thanks for the correct term. I will update the answer

Comment: The example of `obj.prop` vs. `obj[prop]` is good.  Plz add that to your answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var notification in json.responseJSON.Sites){
        console.log(notification);
}
```

Comment: No, I want the value of json.responseJSON.Sites.(variable)
as in json.responseJSON.Sites.LHR   and json.responseJSON.Sites.NJE
console.log(notification) gives me "LHR"
console.log(json.responseJSON.Sites.LHR) gives me 1